# eth0 doesn't start after interfaces modification

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-10.04, interface

Just installed Ubuntu Server 10.04 on VMWare ESXi 4.0.0 (201167) and changed the interfaces file.

My (modified) interfaces file looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.254.159
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.254.0
 broadcast 192.168.254.255
 gateway 192.168.254.1
```

On reboot (or `/etc/init.d/networking restart`)  ifconfig -a shows the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:cc:0b:95
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

So eth0 won't work until I type:

```
ifup eth0
```

I've had this working in previous versions of Ubuntu without any problems, does anyone know how to get this working in 10.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `auto eth0` or append eth0 to `auto lo eth0` to `interfaces` files

Comment: Well, that was pretty stupid - I must have removed it. Thanks.